# Is there any ways to connect admob with Vue Native, Ionic 5

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, vue-native

I tried to convert react native plugins, but It still doesn't work.
I didn't any information on the google. How strange it is.

Comment: Which react native plugin?

Comment: Can you be more specific about question

Comment: why is this tagged ionic-framework when you are using vue-native

Comment: So, is it Vue Native or Ionic? Please, fix your tags